# What is the solution of this recursion, that's defined in terms of a sum, but with this $1$ odd twist?

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations, closed-form, oeis

$$
F(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} F\left(\left\lfloor\frac{i}{5}\right\rfloor\right)
$$

I encountered this odd looking functional equation, while perusing the site yesterday. I'd be interested in seeing a formal/elegant solution method to find $F(n)$. My solution method is a bit ad-hoc.

Hint: To actually find the solution, start off by graphing. From there, I'd see if there is an formal/elegant proof method to justify the intuition.

Here's a challenge question, can your solution method be easily generalized to handle,$
F(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} F\left(\left\lfloor\frac{i}{k}\right\rfloor\right)
$, where $k$ is now a positive number?

(I intend to post an answer, but I'll wait about $3$ or more days)

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the recurrence to $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(\lfloor n/k\rfloor)$ for $n>0$ and normalize it by putting $F(0)=1$. We can draw a graph of $F(n)$ but it is not easy to find even asymptotic growth of $F(n)$ from it. Nevertheless, such sequences are known and for particular values of $k$ belong to the on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences: [$k=2$](https://oeis.org/A000123), [$k=3$](https://oeis.org/A005704), [$k=4$](https://oeis.org/A005705), and [$k=5$](https://oeis.org/A005706). There is a lot of references, especially for the first sequence.